# Earliest usage of 力不从心?

Tags: history

What's the earliest usage of 力不从心?

The earliest I've seen is:

> 《後汉书·西域传》
>
> 今使者大兵未能得出, 如諸國力不從心, 東西南北自在也。

Anything earlier than 后汉书? 445 is, apparently, the given year for completion of 后汉书.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most useful resources for checking this sort of thing is the huge database from Academia Sinica (中央研究院), [漢籍電子文獻](http://hanji.sinica.edu.tw/).

The earliest instance in 漢籍 is just what you cite, 後漢書西域傳, but 漢籍 also lets you look at the context, which can sometimes give a more precise date.  It turns out this line is attributed to 廣武帝, in 廣武二十一年. This would be A.D. 46-7.

Works such as *Shi ji*, *Han shu*, *San guo zhi*, *Hou Han shu*, and so on, often incorporate early original documents; if you want to date something, this can be very helpful.

I also can't help feeling that this expression is related to the famous line 七十而從心所欲 in the Analects. 從心 is 從心所欲, right?

Comment: tw does such a better job of preserving info

Answer (score 1):

Nope. I just look up the Chinese Idiom Dictionary, and I just find out the same answer. But be aware of this, 后汉 is not the same as Han Dynasty.

BTW, I am a native Chinese speaker and passion about history.

And you are messing Simplified Chinese with the original version Chinese.Yeah, 後 is what I am saying